# Can't Deploy additionnal packages in a pipeline job

Tags: ibm-cloud, continuous-delivery

I use a nodejs App in the continuous delivery. Recently I installed a package (puppeteer) which fails to launch because it requires some shared librairies (xlib). This issue is documented ([here](https://techoverflow.net/2018/06/05/how-to-fix-puppetteer-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libx11-xcb-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory/)) and I just need to install additionnal packages.

So I have added in my "BUILD" job additional lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
npm install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y --fix-missing  libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 .......
```

It installs successfully (couple of errors though), the build job ends with success. (6 upgraded, 133 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.)
But when I start the App in the "deploy" stage. the file is still missing!

Am I installing this properly?

2020-05-20T08:27:03.83+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Unhandled Rejection at: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
   2020-05-20T08:27:03.83+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR /home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-756035/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Where do you deploy to? Cloud Foundry, Kubernetes, VPC, ...?

Comment: to cloud foundry. Could it have to do with PATH?

Comment: I am using the latest pipeline image (2.6)

Comment: My guess is that you install into the pipeline image, not to your Cloud Foundry buildpack

Comment: humm could be something like this, but then I miss the complete continuous delivery process. My understanding was that I was building an artifact image that would later be deployed in the next stage. That is were I do the npm install too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it sorted. data_Henrik was right from start.

What I was doing above in the deployment jobs was useless. It is NOT what will be deployed with the APP.

Instead, you need to deploy "multi buildpack" with (for my APP) the standard nodejs buildpack and also a buildpack specially made to install debian dependencies : https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack. example here: https://ict.swisscom.ch/2019/11/no-root-access-no-debian-packages-on-cloud-foundry-thats-past-with-the-apt-buildpack/

So for my nodejs app it ends up with:
1- a specific apt.yml files containing the list of dependencies (note I had to add a couple more eg libgbm-dev)
2- a specific multi-buildpack.yml containing the list of buildpacks

And that is it. I run the usual build and deploy jobs..

Answer (score 0):

you may want to discuss this problem directly on our public Slack.
Self register here: https://ic-devops-slack-invite.us-south.devops.cloud.ibm.com/
then ask your question here https://ibm-devops-services.slack.com/

I suspect you should add the missing dependencies to your package.json

Comment: Thanks Eric, but the registration link doesn't work for me...I wanted initially to add the packages in my package.json, but I couldn't: these libs are apparently linux shared librairies that have to be part of the operating system (guessing here). I could not find them as an npm package to include in my app.

Answer (score 0):

sorry to hear that registration did not work.
Simply go here https://ic-devops-slack-invite.us-south.devops.cloud.ibm.com/
put your email address
and get your invite.

You should receive an email to register - pick a password of your choice.

Anyhow, I'll check on your issue ASAP

Answer (score 0):

1 - ensure puppeteer dependencies are installed without any errors.
You wrote "It installs successfully (couple of errors though)"
and "55 not upgraded".
Possibly, dependencies are not fully installed or at the required level.

2 - As suggested in previous comments, you are using the pipeline base image.
You may want to build and use your own custom image, an image that would match all your prereqs.
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/ContinuousDelivery?topic=ContinuousDelivery-custom_docker_images